# Black Screen + No Install

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install ubuntu... but when I booted the disc the computer said it wasn't bootable,It said Please insert bootable media. how can I fix this?

Comment: The disk may not be created properly. Try creating a live USB(if your system is bootable from USB) or live cd again.

Answer (score 0):

How did you mount the disk?

Did you just place the .iso onto it, or did you actually mount it?

If you haven't mounted it that explains the issue you are having. Best way to mount onto a cd on windows 7 is to install the free software Infra Recorder from http://infrarecorder.org/ and then burn the .iso onto it through; actions -> burn image (in the menu).

Now you can boot from the CD. Hope this helps

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes, I understand how commenting etc works on this, I just don't have the reputation (yet) to be able to. How am I supposed to help when I can't comment? So, I posted an answer instead.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Have updated. Actually answers question now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: no problem!  I get notifications to review and edit new posts, and don't always have the time that I should to look at them.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thank you for understanding. Look at my rep now :)
*Beams Brightly*